# Restore Elasticsearch 6.3.0 snapshot locally

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a  elasticsearch(v6.3.0) snapshot that is stored on AWS S3. This snapshot is taken from a existing staging environment. I want to restore this snapshot to local elasticsearch which is running on a docker. Please provide me some direction for to restore.

Otherwise please provide another approach to bring the staging elasticsearch to my local computer.